# Sabre API - Hotel Booking Request - CVC Validation Error

Tags: sabre

I am creating following Sabre Hotel booking request to book a hotel room but getting CVC validation error.

My question is that by looking the below response, it is clear that we have to set CVC code somewhere in the Request but `Sabre` is not providing any option or variable to set this in the `XML` request.

How can i set this CVC value to resolve the issue?

**Request:**

```
<OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.2.0">
        <Hotel>
            <BasicPropertyInfo RPH="2" />
            <Guarantee Type="GDPST">
                <CC_Info>
                    <PaymentCard Code="AX" ExpireDate="2012-12" Number="1234567890" />
                    <PersonName>
                        <Surname>TEST</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </CC_Info>
            </Guarantee>
            <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" />
            <SpecialPrefs>
                <WrittenConfirmation Ind="true" />
            </SpecialPrefs>
        </Hotel>
    </OTA_HotelResRQ>
```

and after hitting the above request, getting following response string-

**Response:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:ConversationId>SabreConversationMyFlightSearch</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML" />
            <eb:Action>OTA_HotelResLLSRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>4300704404584800230</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-08-23T11:14:18</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESC!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3240444724556748409!1141634!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client.Validation</faultcode>
            <faultstring>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <stl:ApplicationResults xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="NotProcessed">
                    <stl:Error timeStamp="2017-08-23T06:14:18-05:00" type="Validation">
                        <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                            <stl:Message>cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'integer'.</stl:Message>
                            <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
                        </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    </stl:Error>
                </stl:ApplicationResults>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is this error persistent? I've tried the same RQ and I am not getting any validation errors. The request looks fine.

Comment: yes. it is continuously coming.

Comment: Is this still an issue?